# Check if a directory contains only subdirectories and no files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a directory which has subdirectories like this:

```
C:\FILES
C:\FILES\DONE
```

I want to check that FILES contains no files:

```
if not exist C:\FILES\*.* (
  echo No files to process.
  exit /b 
)
```

But the test "not exist ..." is never true because of the subdirectory.

Any ideas on how to check if the directory has any files that are not directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get the list of files and if it fails, there are no files

```dos
dir /a-d "c:\files\*" >nul 2>nul || (
    echo No files to process
    exit /b
)
```

If there are no files, the `dir /a-d` command (the switch means exclude directories) will fail. `||` is a conditional execution operator that will execute the following commands if the previous one has failed.

Answer (score 1):

Only when there are files, the `for` execute the `goto`.

```
for %%a in (C:\FILES\*.*) do goto files
echo No files to process.
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code:

```
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b c:\FILES\') do goto :files
echo No files found
pause
goto:eof
:files
echo Files found
pause
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if exists sub-directories on this level:

```
(DIR /D "C:\FILES\" | findstr /i /p /r /c:"2 Directory" > nul 2> nul) && echo "No directories except current and parent."
```

This simple inline command could be easy adapted for any situation ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
if not exist dir c:\FILES\*.* /a:-d (
```

You can find more on [dir here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true)

**PS**

I do not have DOS at my reach. So I can't test the above code snippet. But I think it is close to what you are looking for.If not something very close to that should work.